# custom Django Rest Framework json output format(CBV)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

**What do I want?**

For Success:

```
{
  "data": {
    "id": 123,
    "name": "Django"
  }
}
```

For Errors (serializer errors or other exceptions):

```
{
  "error": {
    "name": ["this field is required"]
  }
}
```

**My Code:**

```
renderer_classes = [CustomJSONRenderer]  # adds 'data' key

def get_exception_handler(self)
    return custom_exception  # adds 'error' key to output for errors
```

**My Output:**

for Success: (Good)

```
{
  "data": {
    "id": 123,
    "name": "Django"
  }
}
```

For Error: (Wrong)

```
{
    "data": {  # Remove this key
        "error": {   # this should be first key for output
            "name": ["This field required"]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question, It seems that your already said what you've to do, so what is the problem?

Comment: @aliva Look again at the most bottom code. He need to remove `data` key when there is an error occurred.

 @Ravi Gadila, thanks man for tips, i'm looking for the custom responses.